# Serving ".html" files without the extension with Caddy

Tags: webserver, caddy, caddyfile

I have the following `html/` directory and a Caddyfile:

```
Caddyfile
html/
├── 404.html
├── 500.html
├── about.html
├── blog
│   ├── one.html
│   ├── two.html
│   └── three.html
├── blog.html
├── home.html
├── projects.html
└── static
    ├── css
    │   └── site.css
    ├── images
    │   ├── favicon.ico
    └── js
        └── highlight.pack.js
```

I'd like requests to resolve in the following way:

- `localhost:8080/` or `localhost:8080` -> serves `html/home.html`
- `localhost:8080/about` -> serves `html/about.html`
- `localhost:8080/about/` -> serves `html/about.html` -> rewrites URI to `/about`
- `localhost:8080/about.html` -> serves `html/about.html` -> rewrites URI to `/about`
- `localhost:8080/blog/one` -> serves `html/blog/one.html
- 404 and 500 errors serve `html/404.html` and `html/500.html` respectively

I feel like I have it *almost* right but the combination of `uri` and `try_files` is not producing the exact effect as described above:

```
http://localhost:8080

uri strip_suffix .html
try_files {path}.html

handle_errors {
    rewrite * html/{err.status_code}.html
    file_server
}

file_server {
    index home.html
    root html
}
```

Do the requests for `.html` extension URIs have to be redirected somehow to their non-`.html` equivalents?